# CSS: set element's height relative to its content

Tags: html, css

[image: here is the pic]
Above is the actual pic, below is the html structre

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
  <div class="text">
```

Here, the `.image` would have different height due to its provider (96px or 95px). and the `box`'s height is set to `overflow: auto;` so there will be no extra white space.

But here comes another problem, the `text` in the right sometimes gets too long and generates extra white space.(the `text` got margin )

Solutions seem abundant. For the simplest one, I could just set all their height to 95px. But I feel uncomfortable doing that.

Is there any elegant solution?

I think one would be ajust the `text`'s spacing, margin according to its sibling`image` or parent`box`; or I could limit the height of the `text` somehow.(I tried set height to 100%, but its not working)

Comment: Any problem using ellipsis?

Comment: I'm debugging my text now.....

Comment: Try adding `overflow-y: hidden` to your `.box`. Also if your image are either 96px or 95px height, you could simply add a `height="95"` attribute to your `<img>` element and set your `.box` height to 95px as well.

Comment: @sbooob Adding `overflow hidden` + `height 95px` is working. Is there any other solutions?